# Таблица на сайт через админку WordPress + получение её через API

Tags: wordpress, rest

Подскажите, есть ли плагины для **WordPress**'а, позволяющие добавлять таблицы?
Причём плагины, доступ к которым есть через **REST API**.

К слову, есть замечательный плагин *TablePress*, но обратиться к таблице через него не представляет возможности.

Может быть есть вариант свой маршрут прописать как-то?

Comment: Что значит  "не представляет возможности"? Таблицы TablePress-а это кастомный тип контента (насколько я помню). REST API вполне позволяет работать с любыми типами контента.

Comment: @SeVlad, подскажите пожалуйста, а как мне к таблице этой подцепиться через REST API?

Comment: К сож, не подскажу, тк не только не понимаю что значит "подцепиться" (можно записать, извлечь, а подцепиться... это что-то не то), но и вообще с REST API я очень мало работал. Тут я больше теоретик. Но уверен, что в документации https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/  всё можно найти.